# Tomcat Server gets unresponsive

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, mysql-workbench, multi-user

I am new in JPA and java Web App development.Please help me.

Overview:
I am developing one java web application with Apache Tomcat Server [Version 7.0.70]. And It is multi-user system.

Platform : JVM Java 1.7
Framework : JPA
Database : My-Sql Workbench 6.3 
Jars: MySQL Connector and Eclipse-link

Problem:
Once deploying war file into server 10 clients parallel accessing to the server with 10 unique log-in sessions . After sometime [Uncertain] server gets un-responssive and no database operations working.
After this it need to restart the tomcat server. and system gets work finely. its a continuous process to handle the system.

Image : [My Tomcat Server Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzrwn.jpg)
This image content that shows error when server gets un-responssive

Is there any caching problem

Image persistence.xml : [Persistence Unit Cashing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiCHv.jpg)

Thank you,
Please give me solution.

Comment: include errors here as text, not image. hard to say without code, maybe concurrency errors?